# Textarea created through jQuery - but not editable, why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

I have this simple HTML code...

```
<div onclick='jsComment();'>Click to comment</div>
```

And the `jsComment()` function just creates a form with a textarea and a button and replaces HTML content of the div

```
function jsComment(id){

var form = '<form action="modules.php?name=some_url&id='+id+'" method="post" name="post">';
form += '<b>Post something!</b><br />';
form += '<textarea name="noticia" cols="100" rows="5" maxlength="299" style="overflow: hidden; border: none; border-top: 1px solid LightGrey; margin: 6px;"></textarea><br />';
form += '<input type="hidden" name="noticiaId" value="'+id+'" /><input type="submit" name="op" value="Comment!"></form>';   
jQuery('#noticia_'+id).html(form);

}
```

HTML is generated correctly, but I cannot write in the textarea. When I place the cursor inside the textarea it just disappears... same for the submit button, it appears to be disabled... what's going wrong here? Maybe a CSS question?

Thank you very much

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the rest of the code, that's where the problem seems to be.

Comment: Please include the source code for `jsComment`. It would also be good if you could include a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) replicating the error.

Comment: can you include the code that create the html. it will be helpful to us in finding the problem.

Comment: jsComment() function code added to the main message. thanks

Comment: Note the overflow: hidden; was just a try to fix this issue, cannot be the issue itself

Comment: Can you put this up on jsFiddle.net? Also - what are the dimensions of the textarea and do you have it going inside a label tag that belongs to another element?

Comment: it is working http://jsfiddle.net/FvnKd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Use .replaceWith() instead, see jsfiddle for comparison.

I tried multiple ways to fix this the best way I could come up with is to write the  regularly (not dynamically) and show it onclick.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/tFxDs/ for all the options I tried

```
$("commentcontainer").click(function() {
    $(this).html("").next(".textareacontainer").show();
});
```

Comment: i think that his problem lies in the fact that he uses `html()` to add the form to the DOM. If you use `append()` or `prepend()` everything works correctly (or `replaceWith()` as i suggested)

Comment: @Nicola You're completely right, now the question is, why doesn't it work with .html()?

Comment: Thanks! replaceWith() worked fine! I didn't know about that function, I've always used html() before

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is here

```
 jQuery('#noticia_'+id).html(form);
```

you should use

```
 jQuery('#noticia_'+id).replaceWith(form);
```

i created a simplified fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dzytP/

Generally speaking, you should append elements to the DOM and not change the html to have things like `<FORM>` work when added dynamically

Comment: Thanks! replaceWith() worked fine! I didn't know about that function, I've always used html() before

Answer (score 0):

ehm.. tried to replicate your problem....   but couldn't.. look at this fiddle. This is the way I would do it.. of course you can still include your IDs..   http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/CpmvV/